# Can I have a less validating StAX parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml, streaming, xml-parsing, stax

I have the following invalid XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page num="1" crop_box="0, 0, 595, 842" media_box="0, 0, 595, 842" rotate="0">
    <Flow id="1">
        <Para id="1">
            <Line box="90, 754.639, 120.038, 12">
                <Word box="90, 754.639, 22.6704, 12">This</Word>
            </Line>
        </Para>
    </Flow>
</Page>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page num="1" crop_box="0, 0, 595, 842" media_box="0, 0, 595, 842" rotate="0">
    <Flow id="1">
        <Para id="1">
            <Line box="90, 754.639, 120.038, 12">
                <Word box="90, 754.639, 22.6704, 12">This</Word>
            </Line>
        </Para>
    </Flow>
</Page>
```

While it is structurally invalid (it has two root elements and the XML prologue shows up twice), it can still be correctly parsed (ie. the tags are correct and content is also correct).

So, the question is, is there a StAX (or any other streaming based) XML parser in Java that would allow me to do that? I have checked all options in **XMLInputFactory** but none of them seem to allow the parser to accept this kind of malformed XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i seriously doubt you will be able to get any standard java tool to parse the documents as is.  however, you could find the boundaries yourself and parse the individual documents.  just look for occurrences of `"<?xml"`.

Comment: I did something close to that ( https://gist.github.com/2350438 ) but the main issue is that I'm not happy with the performance, it would be much simpler if I could just receive the tokens directly and not care about validating the file.

Comment: And looks like there is a less validating parser, Woodstox in PARSING_MODE_FRAGMENT ( http://woodstox.codehaus.org/4.0.7/javadoc/com/ctc/wstx/api/WstxInputProperties.html#PARSING_MODE_FRAGMENT ). Gonna try it out.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares - actually, looks like PARSING_MODE_DOCUMENTS is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just write yourself a `FilterReader` or `FilterInputStream` derived class that returns EOF once when it sees a new XML header.

Comment: Not sure how this helps, you mean return EOF and then reuse the same filter to start again?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Reuse the entire stream to parse the next document. Of course you need to know when it has *really* reached EOF, so you need to add a method so you can test for that.

Answer (score 0):

i have made an parse method that return me message which is class of the Type Message(its my class that has despction of the contents of Rss i need to filter out)

my method goes as followes

```
    @Override
public List<Message> parse() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Message currentMessage = new Message();
    RootElement root = new RootElement(RSS);
    final List<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();
    Element channel = root.getChild(CHANNEL);
    Element item = channel.getChild(ITEM);

    item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {

        @Override
        public void end() {
            message.add(currentMessage.copy());     
        }
    });

    item.getChild(TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setTitle(body);
        }
    }); 

    item.getChild(LINK).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        @Override
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setLink(body);   
        }
    });
    item.getChild(DESCRIPTION).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setDescription(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild(PUB_DATE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setDate(body);
        }
    });
    /*item.getChild(IMAGE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setImage(body);
        }
    });*/

    try {
        Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return message;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can't see how this is related to my question, really.